# STS unable to resolve target type with java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I have the below code that errors out in STS(3.8.4) saying,

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<String,Object>` to `Map<? extends
>   K,? extends V>`

```
this.attributeMappings = new HashMap<>(attributeMappings!=null?attributeMappings:Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

Where both the instances of `attributeMappings` are of type `Map<String, Object>`.

Ideally, this shouldn't be a problem with Java 8. Could someone help me to resolve it without making any changes to the source?

PS: The same happens with Eclipse Neon 3

Comment: That's the type accepted by HashMap<>()

Comment: But what's the type of `this.attributeMappings`? That would determine the types of `K` and `V` of the `HashMap` you are creating.

Comment: Using `Collections.emptyMap()` instead of `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` works but I suppose that is 'changing the source'.

Comment: @greg-449 if `this.attributeMappings` and `attributeMappings` are indeed *both* of type `Map<String, Object>`; it does not matter, it would still work.

Comment: @Eugene No, it gave me an error when I tested it.

Comment: @greg-449 that's weird, may be I miss-understood the example? This compiles just fine with eclipse-java-9, javac 8 and 9. `public void test(Map<String, Object> attributeMappings) {
        this.attributeMappings = new HashMap<>(attributeMappings != null ? attributeMappings : Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
    }`

Comment: @Eugene Eclipse Neon.3 doesn't like that, giving the error as reported.

Comment: @soorapadman I try to stick with free IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade, this is an eclipse compiler issue (I've tried searching for it, but no luck) to `Eclipse Oxygen` let's say.

```
Map<String, Object> attributeMappings;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void test(Map<String, Object> attributeMappings) {
    this.attributeMappings = new HashMap<>(attributeMappings != null 
                 ? attributeMappings : Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```

This compiles just fine for me with `javac-8` and in eclipse oxygen latest.

Also notice that you can replace `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` with `Collections.emptyMap()` and it will work also.

Comment: The final release of Eclipse Oxygen isn't due until June 17 so it might be worth waiting for that.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm using it for java-9 support, there were some bugs (opened by me) that were fixed only in oxygen...

Comment: I understand that, I am just saying that if someone is going to switch to Oxygen now it is worth waiting a few days for the final release (as I will be doing).

Comment: @Eugene As mentioned, I needed to fix it without code chages. But Oxygen fixed it... Thank you...